# jquery get element without an attribute does not work in code

Tags: javascript, jquery

My page has a table

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-bordered" id="MapDetails" data-role="grid" role="grid" tabindex="0"> .. </table>
```

When i reload with

```
$("#MapDetails").load(url, ...);
```

It becomes

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-bordered" id="MapDetails" data-role="grid" role="grid" tabindex="0">
   <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-bordered" id="MapDetails" aria-activedescendant="MapDetails_active_cell">

<thead>
    ...
</thead>
<tbody>
    ...
</tbody>
```

Now i want to access the child table (second one). when i try

```
$("#MapDetails:not([role='grid'])")
```

in the browser it seems to works correctly (.children() then shows a thead and tbody element)
but the same query when written in javascript code doesnot work at all.

Comment: You can't have a table inside a table like that.

Comment: you also can't have two elements with the same `id`

Comment: the .load function places the returned HTML *into* the matched element. Therefore when you're reloading the table, the .load function is putting the table into the table.

Comment: You should load it into the parent element, so the new table replaces the old one, instead of being put inside it.

Comment: Thanks Barmar & D.R. now i have a single table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [jQuery Load Function](http://api.jquery.com/load/) loads data from the server and places it INSIDE of the matched element.

I'm running off of the assumption that the page is nothing but the table.

Therefore, when you're calling `$('#MapDetails').load(url, ...);` you're reloading the page, which is the table, and placing that data *inside* of the existing table. You could do `$('#MapDetails').parent().load(url, ...);` then you wouldn't have to worry about accessing the child table.